# How to remove foreign key constraints from two tables which is referenced to each other?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables A and B which is referenced each other. A is referenced to B and vice versa. I cant add or remove any data from these two tables. I neither can remove foreign key constraints from these table. Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

then alter your tables as you like, then do

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: i have tried and its not working. I want to break the relatioship as well. Thnx for your reply